# Filter some but not all subdomains in Google Analytics filter

Tags: regex, google-analytics

The domain I want to track has a variety of subdomains such as:

- sanfrancisco.domain.com
- vienna.domain.com
- madrid.domain.com
- etc.

I also have a 'main' domain with a couple subdomains that I want included in one profile:

- domain.com
- cities.domain.com
- countries.domain.com

What sort of filter with regex can I setup to exclude the individual cities, but include the main domain and selected broad category subdomains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This regex will match only the 'main' domain and this with prefixe 'cities.' or 'countries.' :

```
^(?:(?:cities|countries)\.)?domain.com$
```

Some explainations :

`^` start with

`?:` non capturing group (ie you dont want to capture this group but only check the global match)

`cities|countries` 'cities' or 'countries'

`\.` a dot

`?` 0 or 1 time

`domain.com` explicit...

`$` end with

You can add any word with a pipe after `cities|countries` like `cities|countries|continents`.

Comment: Today, you are my hero. I have been doing rails so much I was doing ||